# React Modal with axios infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, axios, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, infinite-loop

The print statement in my `if (this.props.currentNode.getAttribute("label").toLowerCase() === "data")`
is being called infinite times which keeps on printing `in modal` and sending a post request until the modal is closed.

**This does not happen when I put the post call in `ComponentDidMount`**

Can anyone please explain why this is happening and what I can do to avoid this?

```
class ConfigurationModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectSource: [],
    };
  }

  el = document.createElement("div");

  componentDidMount() {
    modalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    modalRoot.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  jsonIsEmpty = (obj) => {
    return obj === "[object Object]" ? true : false;
  };

  render() {
    // The gray background
    const backdropStyle = {
      position: "fixed",
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)",
      padding: 50,
    };
    if (this.props.currentNode.getAttribute("label").toLowerCase() === "data") {
      console.log("in modal")
      http.post("configure_get_sources", {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
      })
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({ selectSource: res.data });
        });

      var tempConfig = this.jsonIsEmpty(
        this.props.currentNode.getAttribute("configuration")
      )
        ? {}
        : JSON.parse(this.props.currentNode.getAttribute("configuration"));
      let renderedSources = this.state.selectSource.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <option value={item} key={i} selected={item === tempConfig["Source"]}>
            {item}
          </option>
        );
      });
      return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div className="backdrop" style={backdropStyle}>
          <Modal.Dialog>
            <Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Title>Configure Node</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>
              <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                  <label className="col-md-4">Data Source: </label>
                  <select className="col-md-7" id="dataSelect">
                    {renderedSources}
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div className="row col-md-3"></div>
              </div>
            </Modal.Body>

            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.props.onClose}>
                Close
              </Button>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.props.saveModal}>
                Save changes
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal.Dialog>
        </div>,
        this.el
      );
    }
    
    return "";
  }
}

export default ConfigurationModal;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying component's state inside `render`, this causing an infinity loop. Because of `react` re-rendering component after each `props` or `state` change. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html